# Android in app billing with external subscription payment

Tags: android, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am fully aware of Google rules regarding in app payments, but I am still not sure if my case pass these rules or it violate them, so I wanted to make sure and see if anyone have a better answer.

Basically I have a website where people register and buy a subscription for a X service, recently I built an Android app to correspond to the service of the website, my Android app shows a message to the users saying that if they want to buy premium subscription they have to go to my website, register and buy it there, the question is does it violate Google rules?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you clarify just what is X service is doing? The exception for IAP requirement depends on the service nature, and you don't include enough detail about it.

Comment: Basically the service is a managed content service and login in with your website user will unlock the premium features of the app as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

You are not allowed to hint that users can spend money somewhere else. Its also not allowed to link to external resources where the user can spend money.

Netflix is an example for this.

Netflix users can use the App with the account they created on the website.
Users that create an account from the App are forced to go through in app purchases.

Netflix App is not allowed to hint that users can get it cheaper through the Netflix website.

Comment: What if my Android app does not allow people to register within the app, only via the website?

Comment: If you can do better than multibillion dollars companies with an army of lawyers, then go ahead.